# Anchor tag with href does not direct user to correct page

Tags: html, url, razor

I have a .cshtml page on my website, and I need to add a link to the contact page of another website. I added the code:

```
<a href="http://www.website.com/address.html>Text</a>
```

This link works fine for internal users accessing my webpage. However, any external users just get sent to the "website.com" main page, not the "website.com/address.html" page. I changed the link to:

```
<a href="http://website.com/address.html">
```

and this resolved the issue for external users, but caused the internal users to get "Page not found" error.

Does any have an idea as to why I cannot link users to the "Address.html" page?

Comment: It is unlikely this has anything to do with razor. Check the HTML that is generated to verify that the URL is what you expect it to be. Having verified, it is possible that there is some configuration having to do with your intranet that is causing the undesired redirect. You may need to work with your server and network teammates on this one.

Comment: I had checked the HTML, and the URL is fine. I had figured it might be a problem with the server configurations. Thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the issue. Instead of using

```
href="//website.com/path
```

I used:

```
href="/path"
```

This caused the link to be appended to the current website URL. This worked if a user was internal (www.website.com) or external (website.com).